# The date selected with datepicker takes the value of the previous day

Tags: date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-format, jquerydatetimepicker

When I select the date 16-01-2021, this value comes to my input field. But when I look at the value received by the service, I get the value "{15.01.2021 21:00:00}". how can i fix this?

Comment: I think your time is in gmt instead of local, that is why you get a date 3 hours earlier. is the time you get on your server or before the post?

Comment: I think you are right. When I debug in the browser, the correct date comes, but when I debug it by visual studio, it brings 3 hours before. So how can I solve this?

Comment: if your local time in your country is 3 hours earlier then all you have to do is set up datepicker to work with moment.js and set it up to pick up your local time. but if tommorow you end up having clients from other countries you will have to translate their time to you local time in order to be able to keep them inline